# Plotting arrays of coordinates that are all under one column in CSV table?

Tags: csv, xy, formatting

I am trying to project specific route paths that all have coordinate points under a single column. Each row represents a different route path. Some of them go on for more than 100 coordinate points so I am trying to figure out the most efficient way to display the data.

If there were just one set of longitude and latitude coordinates, it would be very easy as I could just use text to columns feature to separate them into X and Y components. However, doing this with this data set would generate a lot of columns and make the uploading process very tedious.

I have attached a picture of the data.

[image]

Comment: Is there any difference in the formatting in the separator between lat,lon and lon,lat? It looks like the lat/lon within a pair are separated by a comma and the coordinate pairs are separated by a comma and a space. If this is the case I think I have the answer.

Comment: @Kingfisher The lat/lon pairs (i.e 35.96347, -83.91749) are separated by a comma AND a space. The coordinate pairs (i.e.([35.96347,-83.91749],[35.9635,-83.91758]) are ONLY separated by a comma.

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of nodes a line could have?
Is the coordinate order (lat, lon) or (lon, lat)?

Comment: @Kingfisher can you please clarify by what you mean by nodes? I'm fairly new to data terminology lol. I do know that the longest line would have 1888 different fields if separated into two columns where the commas are. So the longest line has 944 plottable points in total. Oh and the order is (lat, lon)

Comment: The node would be individual points that make up the line.

Comment: @Kingfisher Oh ok good to know! So yes the maximum number of nodes would be 944.

Comment: Do you want to plot every point o do you want to plot every single route? Please share some rows of your data.

Comment: @aborruso I want to plot every single route.

Comment: @Kingfisher You mentioned that you had a solution in mind?

Comment: I did, but it requires the coordinates to be XY instead of YX. I was going to suggestion converting to WKT through query. The coordinates would need to be reversed in order for that and I am not sure the process. I will keep looking though.

Comment: @Tarik please share some rows of your CSV